# I can't find a register list or figure to explain MPU6050 I2C communication

Tags: stm32, imu

I'm working on getting an STM32F411 NUCLEO board to communicate with an MPU6050 IMU breakout board, but I've run into an early snag, in that I can't find the list of registers needed to request data from the MPU6050 in the [provided datasheet](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf). I've poked around elsewhere and found a few registers for requesting acceleration and gyro data, but so far there isn't anything I can find anything within official materials. Heck, the actual address is pretty hard to find, only provided as the 7-bit ones and zeroes, rather than as a hex-number, specified for 7 bits.

I'm doing this mainly as practice for writing STM32 code for various chips, so I'd rather not just look up someone else's existing code if I can avoid it.

Comment: The datasheet you linked to refers to Register Map and Register Description document. Have you tried to search it or looked at manufacturer website, or even Adafruit website?

Comment: @Justme I did some poking around and found it, yeah. I feel pretty silly now. I at least know which registers I'm supposed to write to now. I was expecting more demands in terms in initialization and such, but the MPU seems to handle more of that by itself. I guess I'm just used to chips with less... hand-holding? Not sure that's the right term here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Google search: mpu-6050 register map

Result:

https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf